# GCM messages received with delay when phone idle

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm using Amazon Web Services in my application. Especially sending SNS messages to mobile endpoint. All things realized from official Amazon and Google documentation and works perfect. But few days i'm fighting with one strange bug. After some inactive time GCM messages received with huge delay(10 min). If i turn off/on WiFi connection, after that i receive all messages immediatelly. So it looks like WiFi/Mobile internet going to sleep and in this state GCM receive with delay. Can somebody explain how can i wakeup internet connection for to not have this delay? From my view turn off/on wifi it's not elegant solution :)

Here is my receiver code:

```
    public class hsGCMListenerService extends GcmListenerService {    
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SNS message received: "+ data.toString()); 
            doProcessSNSMessageAndInformMainActivity(data);
        }
    }

private void doProcessSNSMessageAndInformMainActivity(Bundle AMessage) {
   Intent msgReceived = new Intent(AppCommon.SNS_BROADCAST_MSG);  
   msgReceived.putExtra(AppCommon.C_SNSRequest_Result, AppCommon.C_SQSRequest_UploadDataOnS3);   

   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(msgReceived);
}
```

Also thre's no errors messages, just a big delay.

My manifest file.

```
    <permission android:name="com.hssoft.cashassistmobileorders.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.hssoft.cashassistmobileorders.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".common.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_FullName"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_ShortName" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.hssoft.cashassistmobileorders" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.hssoft.cashassistmobileorders.gcm.hsGCMListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.hssoft.cashassistmobileorders.gcm.hsInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.hssoft.cashassistmobileorders.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />
    </application>   
</manifest>
```

Declaring Broadcast receiver in MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                AppCommon.doFillSettings();
                if (AppCommon.WorkDeviceIsConfigured) {
                    doSendSQSRequest(AppCommon.C_SQSRequest_RegistrateDevice);
                }

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean(AppCommon.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false)) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver. Token creation problem");
                }
            }
        };

        mSNSBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.hasExtra(AppCommon.C_SNSRequest_Result)) {
                    doRefreshData(intent.getExtras().getInt(AppCommon.C_SNSRequest_Result));
                }
            }
        }; .....
```

Comment: are you sure the implementation on client and server complies with the documentation?

Comment: Absolutelly. As i wrote before, until device going to sleep i receive all messages immediatelly, but after sleep i have to wait delay or reconnect my internet connection

Comment: that is expected behaviour, do you have a registered `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Yes in main Activity. But first point in this logic is onMessageReceived after that we send broadcast message. In my situation no any incoming message in onMessageReceived

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw in the comments and question, this is the answer.

If you declare a `BroadcastReceiver` in the Activity class and not as a standalone receiver that is also declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, it will die when the application dies and will not be woken up upon sending a new GCM push.

What you want to do is declare a `BroadcastReceiver` that will be exposed out via the manifest and this way it'll wake your application up when a new push arrives

Comment: I have updated my first post. As you can see all needed services described in manifest. But i want to repeat, problem not in broadcast receiver. Problem in hsGCMListenerService, after WiFi going to sleep this service receive messages with delay(10 min). The same with Gmail and other applications which use GCM, after some time without any actions i receive notifications with delay, when i turn off/on internet connection i receive all notifications immediatelly. I can reconnect programmatically but from my view should be more elegant solution :)